# Button is supposed to change image after click, but (randomly) changes images of other buttons too

Tags: ios, button, tableview

In my cellForRowAtIndex I initialize a button (it gets shown in every cell in the tableview):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(customActionPressed:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,cell.frame.size.height -15, 160.0f, 15.0f);
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"];
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13.0]];
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 60, 0, 0);
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
[cell addSubview:button];
button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

It has a normal image and if the user clicks on the button, the image changes. Also I get the contents of the button.title from a XML. Therefore I tell it to get the right title from the web. This works fine, but sometimes (not all the time) and also randomly it changes the button from the next cell, or the cell three rows down. I don't know why and couldn't find anything while running with breakpoints/debugger.

```
-(void)customActionPressed :(id)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *owningCell = (UITableViewCell*)[sender superview];

    NSIndexPath *pathToCell = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:owningCell];

    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];

    [self doXMLParsing];
    [sender setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *TableText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [[tabelle objectAtIndex:pathToCell.row] pressed1]]; 
    [sender setTitle:TableText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    ((UIButton *)sender).enabled = NO;
}
```

So maybe someone can see where I went wrong. If you need more code, just say so.

Answer (score 1):

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(customActionPressed:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Try having UIControlEventTouchUpInside instead of UIControlEventTouchDown.

also you create a custom cell and then you can create a property in the class subclassing UITableViewCell for your button and change the image of button through that property.

Also Don't change the image from action of button .You can access the button through cell.yourbuttonName in didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate of tableview and then change the image.

Comment: Could you explain the second part further? I think I don't really undertsand.

Comment: when you create a customcell you can access it by [cell.nameofyourbutton setImage:[UIIMAGE imageNamed:@""]]; if you have multiple items in your cell it's better to have it custom as it is easier to make changes and access it that way

Comment: Oh, okay, yeah than I understood. But even though it's the appdelegate, it doesn't know what to do with "cell.mybutton".

Comment: mybutton is object name for uibutton in custom cell class

Comment: Yes I know, nevertheless I can't interact with it. Always says that the method can't be found.